# Monit Daemon: Apache-Status connection failure

Tags: apache, monitoring, status, monit

I'm setting up a cluster of servers for the company I work at, and I'm using [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) to monitor that all server processes are running and working as they should.

For Apache monitoring, I wanna use the mod_status feature which is explained [here](http://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/MonitorApacheStatus). However, this has turned out quite difficult. As no matter how I configure both Monit and Apache, Monit just keeps reporting a connection failure error (`connection failed to 127.0.0.1:80 [APACHESTATUS via TCP]`).

I followed the instructions on the Monit Wiki without much luck. The Apache status page (`http://127.0.0.1/server-status?auto`) page works in any browser I test it with. I've also tried changing host the from `127.0.0.1` to `localhost` without any luck.

I've tested this setup with Monit versions 4.8.x, 4.10x, and 5.0-beta6, all with the same result. Also, there's not much useful info on Google to help either, as most results are about more trivial and simple problems.

Am I missing something? Or am I just plain stupid maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the authorization in Apache:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

Check Apache access.log and error.log files - which kind of error is reported ?

Comment: Thanks :)... Altho I'd already started doing that 15 min ago and managed to solve the problem only to find your answer here :)... Don't ask why I didn't debug on the Apache side from the start *blames lack of sleep*... lol

Comment: Ok that works, but is there a way to deny the access from the web?